# Insufficient buffer size using WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, kinect

I am modifying the ColorBasic Kinect example in order to display an image overlaid to the video stream. So what I've done is to load an image **with transparent background** (now a GIF but it may change), and write to the displayed bitmap.

The error I'm getting is that the buffer I'm writing to is too small.

I cannot see what the actual error is (I'm a complete newbie in XAML/C#/Kinect), but the WriteableBitmap is 1920x1080, and the bitmap I want to copy is 200x200, so why am I getting this error? I cannot see how a transparent background could be of any harm, but I am beginning to suspect that...

Note that without the last WritePixels, the code works and I see the webcam's output. My code follows.

The overlay image:

```
public BitmapImage overlay = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\users\\user\\desktop\\something.gif"));
```

The callback function that displays the Kinect's webcam (see the default example ColorBasic) with my very small modifications:

```
private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // ColorFrame is IDisposable
    using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame != null)
        {
            FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

            using (KinectBuffer colorBuffer = colorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer())
            {
                this.colorBitmap.Lock();

                // verify data and write the new color frame data to the display bitmap
                if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
                {
                    colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr(
                        this.colorBitmap.BackBuffer,
                        (uint)(colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * 4),
                        ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

                    this.colorBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight));
                }

                if(this.overlay != null)
                {
                    // Calculate stride of source
                    int stride = overlay.PixelWidth * (overlay.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);

                    // Create data array to hold source pixel data
                    byte[] data = new byte[stride * overlay.PixelHeight];

                    // Copy source image pixels to the data array
                    overlay.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

                    this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, overlay.PixelWidth, overlay.PixelHeight), data, stride, 0);
                }

                this.colorBitmap.Unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `overlay.Format.BitsPerPixel` / 8 will be 1  (because it's a gif), but you're trying to copy it to something that is not a gif, probably BGRA (32 bit).  Thus you got a huge difference in size (4x).

---

`.WritePixels` should take in the stride value of the destination buffer, but you past it the stride value of the overlay (this can cause weird problems as well).

---

And finally, even if it went 100% smooth your overlay will not actually "overlay" anything, it will replace -- since I don't see any alpha bending math in your code.

Switch your .gif to a .png (32bit) and see if that helps.

Also, if you're looking for an AlphaBltMerge type code:  I wrote the entire thing here.. it's very easy to understand.

---

[Merge 2 - 32bit Images with Alpha Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727167/how-to-merge-a-picture-into-a-writeablebitmap/25729643#25729643)